# Excel runs VBA code and then crashes

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I have been using this simple code for a number of years in various versions of Excel upto 2010, this is to timestamp entries on one sheet, by entering a number in column A the entry time will be inserted into the adjacent cell in Column B.
I recently purchased a tablet as this would provide provide a better use for the spreadsheet. The tablet is running Windows 8 and Office 2013. When I run the sheet the time is entered into the cell, but then then immediately the message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" and Excel closes.
I have loaded Excel 2010 on the tablet as I thought the problem may have been Excel 2013, but this didn't work either.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim c As Integer
Dim f As Integer

c = ActiveCell.Column
r = ActiveCell.Row

If c <> 1 Then End
Cells(r - 1, c + 1) = Time$
Cells(r - 1, c + 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim c As Long
Dim f As Long

c = ActiveCell.Column
r = ActiveCell.Row

If c <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If r = 1 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(r - 1, c + 1) = Now
    Cells(r - 1, c + 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

1. change the DIM's
2. error tests
3. avoid re-entry

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and shorter version is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))) Is Nothing) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Now
        Target.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

And this solution works also when entering multiple values in column 1.